# "Join" admins of different tables into a string

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

## The real issue

**Involved tables and their columns**

```
accounts      [id,name]
rooms         [id,name,topic,owner]
room_admins   [account_id,room_id]
```

#### Q: Get all rooms with their admin- and owner ids.

Where "all" of course has a condition to it (above: WHERE name LIKE ...)
Admins and owners should be returned in one column just called "admins". I tried to concatenate them above into one string.

## What I tried

I came up with a solution, but it requires the use of an omnious external variable ":room_id" that changes on each outer SELECT and makes therefore no sense at all.

```
SELECT id,name,topic,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(admins.account_id) AS owner
        FROM
        (SELECT account_id
        FROM `room_admins`
        WHERE room_id=:room_id
        UNION
        SELECT owner FROM `rooms` WHERE id=:room_id) admins) AS owner
FROM `rooms`
WHERE name LIKE "%htm%" OR topic LIKE "%htm%" LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Probably you might reconsider why you want owners and admins grouped together. Your schema will not perform to answer that query. The best solution by far will be to merge the owner with the admin in the next layer (EG: PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I haven't given this a deep thought... but I've just came up with this (sample data would have been useful to make tests... so this is just a blind answer).

```
select id, name, topic, group_concat(owner_admin) from (
    select id, name, topic, owner owner_admin from rooms
    union
    select id, name, topic, account_id from rooms
    left join room_admins on id = room_id
) s
where name like "%htm%" or topic like "%htm%"
group by id, name, topic
```

Basically I'm just generating a derived table with owner and admins mixed in one column. Then performing the grouping on that mixed column.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, when you want to select and display dependent data, you want to use a JOIN. In this case, you want to join the rooms with their admins, so basically:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.topic, a.id
FROM rooms r
LEFT JOIN admins a
ON r.id = a.room_id
WHERE :condition
```

Since you have one additional admin not in the admins table (the room owner), you have to (self) join a second time:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.topic, a.id
FROM rooms r
LEFT JOIN admins a
ON r.id = a.room_id
LEFT JOIN rooms o
ON r.id = o.id
WHERE :condition
```

This doesn't give us any new information, but your question states that you want to return the list of admins in a single field. So, finally, putting it all together:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.topic, GROUP_CONCAT(a.id)
FROM rooms r
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT id, room_id FROM admins
  UNION SELECT room.owner AS id, rooms.id AS room_id FROM rooms
) a
ON r.id = a.room_id
WHERE :condition
GROUP BY r.id
```

But to avoid this ugly sub-select-union clause, I'd advise you to put the room owner into your admin table too.